# Binding TextBlock to static variable

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm attempting to bind `TextBlock` to static variable. I have read some guides and topics and this is what i came up with, but so far no results.

XAML:

```xml
xmlns:SQLLog="clr-namespace:DBM.SQLServerLogHandler" //SQLServerLogHandler - folder with LogDisplay class
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:DBM.Converters"
...
<Window.Resources>
        <Converters:StringListToStringConverter x:Key="ListToString"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SQLLog:LogDisplay.LogAdvanced}, Converter={StaticResource ListToString}}" FontSize="12"/>
```

Static class:

```cs
public static class LogDisplay
    {
        private static List<string> _logAdvanced;
        public static List<string> LogAdvanced 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return _logAdvanced; 
            }
            set 
            {
                if(value != _logAdvanced)
                {
                    _logAdvanced = value;
                    if (StaticPropertyChanged != null)
                        StaticPropertyChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                } 
            } 
        }

        public static event EventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
    }
```

And converter

```cs
class StringListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(string))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a String");

            return String.Join(", ", ((List<string>)value).ToArray());
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I also have error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` at `TextBlock`, but program compiles properly.

Results:

No matter what i change in `_logAdvanced` variable, TextBlock stays blank.

Expected results:

TextBlock displays variable.

Comment: Changing property also changes the field. But TextBlock is still blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong `StaticPropertyChanged` implementation and maybe a mistake in xaml `Binding`.

**LogDisplay.cs**

```csharp
public static class LogDisplay
{
    private static List<string> _logAdvanced;
    public static List<string> LogAdvanced
    {
        get
        {
            return _logAdvanced;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _logAdvanced)
            {
                _logAdvanced = value;
                OnStaticPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

    private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**View**

```xaml
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=(SQLLog:LogDisplay.LogAdvanced), Converter={StaticResource ListToString}}" FontSize="12"/>
```

This works for me: `TextBlock` updates its layout when I assign a prepared `List<string>` to `LogDisplay.LogAdvanced` in runtime e.g. by `Button` click.

```csharp
LogDisplay.LogAdvanced = new List<string>
{
    "dddd",
    "ffff"
};
```

And some changes to `StringListToStringConverter`

```csharp
return string.Join(", ", (List<string>)value);
```

BTW, I don't suggest this implementation in case you need UI to be updated when you dinamically modify the `List` in runtime. Now UI will not be updated using `LogAdvanced.Add(someString)`.

Better to use `string` property without Converter and modify it. `LogAdvancedText += someString + ", ";`. Or use templated `ItemsControl` with `Binding` to `ObservableCollection<string>`.

For example:

```xaml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(SQLLog:LogDisplay.LogAdvanced)}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=", "/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```csharp
public static class LogDisplay
{
    private static ObservableCollection<string> _logAdvanced;
    public static ObservableCollection<string> LogAdvanced
    {
        get
        {
            return _logAdvanced;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _logAdvanced)
            {
                _logAdvanced = value;
                OnStaticPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

    private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

By this implementation every `Add()` will cause the UI update

```csharp
LogDisplay.LogAdvanced.Add("Some text");
```

Comment: Thanks, just checking it out. And yes, it will dynamically change. So i guess i will use `+=`.

Comment: @gaijn I've added an `ItemsControl` example. Just for information.

Comment: Ok i did some testing and it's flawless. I have changed List to string and just used +=, also got rid of converter. Yeah, so, that guide i have found was either outdated or just garbage. Either way thanks for help. Marking as solved.